# How to detect if static text button up action

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So, I have three components on my dialog. Two are buttons(PUSHBUTTON), and the other is a static text (LTEXT). But all three controls act 'like' buttons. They are clickable and do whatever they are supposed to do.

So the code looks something like this:

```
// MyDlg.cpp
BOOL MyDlg::DefaultWindowProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch( uMsg)
   {
       ...
       ...
       case WM_COMMAND:
            if( HIWORD(wParam) == 0 )
                dwSelectID = LOWORD(wParam);

            if ( dwSelectID == IDC_BUTTON1 )
                doSomething1();
            else if ( dwSelectID == IDC_BUTTON2 )
                doSomething2();
            else if ( dwSelectID == IDC_STATIC )
                doSomething3();
   }
}
```

It works fine. But the mechanism within those controls works differently. Two buttons runs the respective functions on LBUTTONUP whereas the static runs the respective function on LBUTTONDOWN. I am assuming these different behaviors occur just naturally. Is there something I can do to make the static text work the same?

Comment: The button is sending you a `BN_CLICKED` notification, which is generated when the button is released. The static is sending you a `STN_CLICKED` notification, which is generated when the control is clicked. Numerically they're the same value but semantically they are different. The static control doesn't send a notification on button up - if you want it to, you'd need to sub-class the control and handle the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Okay, I see. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @vaska11 Post an answer if you get it working so that can help others are searching on this issue. Feel free let me know if you still have any problem about this issue. [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview)

Comment: Seems like there's undefined behavior in this code, if `HIWORD(wParam)` is not `0`, `dwSelectID` is never set and god knows what the subsequent checks are doing. Make sure your variables are properly initialized before using them.

Comment: @Havenard You're right. I'm currently dealing with menu only in the dialog, so it wasn't really giving me any hard time. But thanks, I'll watch out for it if there are any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I followed Jonathan's suggestion, which was to use sub-classing.

I subclassed the static control so that the control could capture the `LButtonUp` message. When the subclassed control receives the message, it posts a user-defined message to its parent handle. Then the parent handle takes care of whatever action it needs to deal with.

Simple design of the code would be something like this:

```
// MyDlg.cpp
BOOL MyDlg::DefaultWindowProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch( uMsg)
   {
       ...
       ...
       case SOME_SPECIAL_MSG:
            doSomething3():
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
       case WM_COMMAND:
            if( HIWORD(wParam) == 0 )
                dwSelectID = LOWORD(wParam);

            if ( dwSelectID == IDC_BUTTON1 )
                doSomething1();
            else if ( dwSelectID == IDC_BUTTON2 )
                doSomething2();
       ...
       ...
   }
}
```

```
// Static.cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK UDStatic::StaticProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, DWORD_PTR pwRefData)
{
   UDStatic* pThis = (UDStatic*)pwRefData;
   switch (nMsg)
   {
      ...
      case WM_LBUTTONUP:
          pThis->OnLButtonUp(hWnd, wParam, lParam, pwRefData);
          break;
   }
}
void UDStatic::OnLButtonUp(hWnd, wParam, lParam, pwRefData)
{
    HWND hWndParent = GetParent(hWnd);
    if (hWndParent)
        PostMessage( hWndParent, SOME_SPECIAL_MSG, 0, 0);
}
```

The other way around solving the problem would be simply making a customized text button, so it would inherit the property of the button (BN_CLICKED); Gets the job done.

Comment: I strongly recommend using a customized text button. Assistive technology tools like Narrator won't know that your static control is clickable.

Comment: @RaymondChen Interesting point. I've never tested my app with Narrator, but I'm quite curious to know why. Is that coming from the difference between the two different component?

Comment: Assistive technology tools don't know that you added special click functionality to your static control. They will assume that the static text control is just for holding static text. You can add the [InvokePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-implementinginvoke) to your static text control to say, "Oh, and I'm also clickable."